# How to grep in Linux to find lines with literal asterisks in them?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to use grep files in a Linux directory searching for lines which contain the string `**Post`. The * character is a wildcard, and I can't figure out how to make it literal for this search. For example `\*\*Post` doesn't work. What's the proper way of escaping the * character so it can be used literally in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with a file containing the following text:

```
**Post
*Post
Post
```

And I would like to grep only the one with `**Post`

My command is the following

```sh
grep -irn "\*\*Post"
```

The double quote is important.

The result of the command is

```sh
a.txt:1:**Post
```

While the following command

```sh
grep -irn "\*Post"
```

outputs

```
a.txt:1:**Post
a.txt:2:*Post
```

Comment: I'm trying your command with my files which begin with `log` like this: `grep -irn "\*\*Post" log*` and what I'm getting are a bunch of lines containing the characters `grep`!

Comment: In my case, my filename is `a.txt` so, i can do `grep -irn "\*\*Post" a*` and it still gives me the correct output. 
And I even tried to duplicate the files, I still receive the correct output.

What is the content of your file? 
Can you provide a minimal content?

Comment: I don't know which file contains the pattern. But they are long log files with a bunch of lines that look like `*   0020003802 6600000000 000090ED40 02359C1D01 85ED40023E   . .8.f......??@.5?..??@.>`

Comment: What is exactly the ouput when you execute the grep command?

Comment: Never mind. I had an extra `grep` in my command line. Your solution works. Thanks very much.